# How to get the type of global Array Object function;

Tags: typescript

[STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-8ktngt?file=index.ts)

How can I get the type of e.g. `Array.find` in order to use it to type `pred` of function `findObj`?

```
type XYZ<U> = typeof Array<U>.find;

// what is want
// type XYZ<U> = GIVE_THE_SAME_FUNCTION_TYPE_AS_ARRAY_FIND

const findObj = function<T>( obj: T[], pred: XYZ<T> ): T {

  // pred has type XYZ so it does satisfy find(ARGUMENT)
  obj.find(pred);

  return {} as T;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can extract the type from `find`, but it will only be the type of one of the overloads (the last one). That may or may not be enough for your use case:

```
type XYZ<U> = Parameters<Array<U>['find']>[0];

const findObj = function<T>( obj: T[], pred: XYZ<T> ): T {

  obj.find(pred);
  return {} as T;
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=9&ssc=34&pln=6&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAGgmgLQDwFUB8UC8UAKBDAJzwFsJgICBnJAQQKJFTQG0ByAMwEsA7AE1YC6LAAwCA3ACgJAYwD23SsChc+AeQBGAKyzKArt2nBO8pABU0ACiiytALiinmAgDRQwBCL3vxk5qAEp7UygAbykoay0AOhVeC3dPf0kIj2BdAm5QgF8oPEoHSSypWI1NC2YQ3PsAImqoLJcoC1l-LAxZKLwkoA)

Comment: That is the exact solution I was hoping to find.

Comment: I think thats good for now. Typescript is still in its baby shoes, but its getting there.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
type XYZ<T> =
  (<S extends T>(predicate: (this: void, value: T, index: number, obj: T[]) => value is S, thisArg?: any) => S | undefined) |
  ((predicate: (value: T, index: number, obj: T[]) => unknown, thisArg?: any) => T | undefined);
```

Comment: Thank you. I was trying to avoid that copy paste solution. Otherwise I would have used something like this. :-)